# Terraform state/files disagrees significantly with application timestamp.games

Tags: terraform

So, I have a constellation of Terraform projects. I just built an image of a specific application, which ultimately ends-up updating the tags in the auto-vars file of the corresponding project in the Terraform repository and then applies it, and I noticed that the mtimes are really wacky. It's the 28th, today. The state file shows an mtime of three weeks ago (the 5th) even though I've probably done dozens of tangible releases since then, including having just updated these and applied them a moment ago. The mtime on the auto-vars file and the timestamps in the actual Docker image tags prove it (while taking my word for it that these were applied soon after updating the auto-vars).

```
$ ls -la
total 56
drwxr-xr-x 3 dustin dustin  4096 May 28 14:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 dustin dustin  4096 May  4 12:13 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 dustin dustin  4300 May 16 12:34 main.tf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 dustin dustin    49 May  4 12:13 run.sh
drwxr-xr-x 4 dustin dustin  4096 May  5 15:30 .terraform
-rw-r--r-- 1 dustin dustin   298 May 28 14:38 terraform.auto.tfvars.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 dustin dustin  1409 May  5 15:30 .terraform.lock.hcl
-rw-r--r-- 1 dustin dustin 17556 May  5 15:29 terraform.tfstate.backup
-rw-r--r-- 1 dustin dustin   196 May  4 12:13 variables.tf

$ ls -la .terraform
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 4 dustin dustin 4096 May  5 15:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 dustin dustin 4096 May 28 14:38 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 dustin dustin 4096 May  5 15:29 modules
drwxr-xr-x 3 dustin dustin 4096 May  5 15:30 providers
-rw-r--r-- 1 dustin dustin 1600 May  5 15:29 terraform.tfstate

$ cat terraform.auto.tfvars.json 
{
  "taskdefinition-web-fq-docker-image": "326764833890.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/workflow-web:eb241c0",
  "taskdefinition-app-fq-docker-image": "326764833890.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/workflow-api:20230528143624-abca7cf",
  "taskdefinition-release-version": "20230528143624-abca7cf"
https://boosty.to/safdsfdfd/posts/a21b2822-7f3e-40b9-b93a-a4ff016d9958
```

Comment: I think your states are stored bad. check `terraform state list`